# Should I use flask sqlalchemy many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to design my database, but it is not working out the way I wanted.

Well, I don't think here have table markdown, I will just have my database table and columns below:

`Student: id, fname, lname`

`Course: id, code, section, name, room, period`

Assuming all rows are unique in both `Student` and `Course` table.
How can I design my database so that when I query a student, it will return me all the courses the student take, vice versa, when I query a course, it will return me all the students in that course.

I am using Flask and SQLAlchemy, but have no idea if I should use many-to-many in this case?

Comment: Yes. A `Student` can have many courses, and a `Course` can have many students, so I'd say that's a good candidate for a [`Many-to-Many`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships) relationship. You'll just need a junction table with `user_id` and `course_id` columns.

Comment: Hah, we said almost the exact same thing. Sorry, I didn't see your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You have many students and many courses, and courses can have many students and a student may have many courses.

To do many-to-many, you need a junction or association table with columns that look something like:

```
id | course_id | student_id
---------------------------
1  |         1 |          1
2  |         1 |          2
3  |         2 |          1
4  |         2 |          3
```

Then, in your models, you can use it using SQLalchemy's relationship function:

```
class Classes(Base):
    students = relationship("Students", secondary=junction_table)

class Students(Base):
    classes = relationship("Classes", secondary=junction_table)

junction_table = Table('enrollment', Base.metadata,
   Column('class_id', Integer, ForeignKey('classes.id')),
   Column('student_id', Integer, ForeignKey('students.id')),
)
```

Many to many is tricksy to get set up correctly, but hopefully that's close enough to get you started.

Relevant docs:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: I named my class `Student` and trying to do `ForeignKey('students.id')`, but end up with errors. Afterward I noticed that the `ForeignKey` need to be the same name as class name. Should I use `__tablename__` attribute to override the default naming convention used by Flask-SQLAlchemy?